# Dependency injection in remotely deployed actor?

Tags: akka

When an actor is remotely deployed programmatically as described in the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/remoting.html) under "Programmatic Remote Deployment", is it possible to have the actor configure itself based on configuration files and classes on the remote system?

My use case is similar to what is described [here](http://letitcrash.com/post/55958814293/akka-dependency-injection). I need to inject a service into my actor. The implementation of the service is different depending on where the actor is deployed.

I could just start the actor on the remote system, but I would like a parent actor to supervise it and be able to restart it. As far as I can tell from the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/supervision.html), this supervisory relationship can only be established when a parent creates a child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the actor accesses context.system.settings.config then that will be the local systems' config. So: yes.

Comment: So you mean it will use the config on the system it was deployed to? Is the actor instantiated on the remote system also? I thought it might be instantiated locally and then serialized and sent to the remote system.

Comment: You would you send it to the remote system without calling the constructor of the Actor-class on the receiving end?

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by that last comment. I went back to the documentation and it looks the actor itself is not serialized. The Props, "an immutable and thus freely shareable recipe for creating an actor", is what is actually serialized and sent to the remote system, am I correct?. So the constructor would only get called on the remote system, correct? I was a little mixed up about that and thought the instantiated actor itself might get serialized somehow, but I guess that doesn't make sense.

Comment: If it gets constructed on the remote system and can access the remote config then it seems that remote dependency injection shouldn't be too different from local dependency injection.

Comment: Exactly. You can also very easily verify your assumptions by testing the code :)

Comment: @Victor Klang Are there any examples of injecting a service into a remotely deployed actor where the service class is only known on the remote machine? I am still struggling with this. From what I can tell, the Props object already incorporates all of the parameters of the actor, so I'm not sure how I could deploy an actor remotely and then have it figure out which service to load only after it is deployed. I am somewhat new to both actors and dependency injection, so I apologize for not grasping how to do this.

Comment: Impossible for me to answer without you telling me what you've tried so far and how that doesn't match your use-case.